# iOS 10 Beta (and 10 seed) SCN Action Animation

Tags: animation, scenekit, ios10

SCN Action Animation seems not to be working at all in the current iOS 10 Beta 8.  Either on iPhone or Apple TV.  Seems to work fine with XCODE Beta and iOS 9 devices.

We are seeing that when we do the RUN_ACTION, the animation seems to run once, then never finish and that NODE is now "jammed".  We are trying to make a sample app that will show this same issue when we get some time.

iOS 10 seed and XCODE for 10 SEED is also showing this issue.

Anyone with any information on this?

Comment: There's not enough here for anyone to help diagnose your issue. See [mcve].

Comment: What needs to be here?  It does not work.  Thanks for the downvote instead of asking exactly what you are looking for.  We are running hard here since iOS 10 breaks a bunch of stuff, like SKVIDENODE, SCN Animation, and other items.  This is one of the worst releases that I have seen in 5 years.  When we get a chance to workup an example that exhibits this will post.  This was mainly to see if anyone else has seen this.

Comment: I'm not the one who downvoted. The APIs you mention aren't universally broken for everyone, so unless you provide some specifics about what you're doing with them, nobody will know enough about your problems to be able to help.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but all of the .run_action animations are broke.  They worked find in ios 9 and not in ios 10.  We are fixing them by not animating right now, but clearly there is an issue here.  When you say that they are not broke for everyone, what do you base this information on?

Comment: I find that the template app (what you get when starting a new project and choosing Game > SceneKit) uses `runAction` and works just fine. Show some code that fails for you?

Comment: Apple has noted that this is in issue that they are working on it (I guess).  Will try and get the ticket number.

Comment: For the previous, in general yes.  Works on ios 9.x phones, does not work on ios 10.x phones

Comment: Apple's response: Much appreciated xxxx. The issue number has been sent directly to the engineering team.